# Can I get a transit visa for Tokyo travelling from Shanghai?

Tags: transit, japan, visas-on-arrival, south-african-citizens

South African travelling to Shanghai for holiday, I'd like to go to a show in Tokyo only for the day ...then fly back to Shanghai... will that be allowed at all ?

Comment: Is your Chinese visa multiple entry ? Also I think you're misunderstanding how a transit visa works

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to do this if you meet certain conditions.

1- Your Chinese visa allows multiple entry
2- You have a Japanese visitor visa, as Japan requires South African citizens to have a visa to visit.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_South_African_citizens#Visa_requirements) reference
[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=ZA&JP=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=JP&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) reference
[VisaHQ](http://japan.visahq.co.za/) reference

By the way, a transit visa works if you are on your way somewhere else, what you're looking for is a proper visitor visa in this case